# Layering objects in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I'm quite new to this whole Android Studio and all, but I'm quickly getting used to it all.

Now here's my problem:

I have my main Activity with two screen-filling buttons and I want a checkbox on *top of the first* button.

I've looked all around the Internet, but I couldn't find a single clue.

EDIT: Messing with the order of the objects doesn't work.

This is my XML code (I haven't filled in the functionality, yet):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ggblbl.example.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/button_one"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/button_two"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/checkbox"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

PS: I don't know if this helps, but I use API 15 and Android Studio 2.3.2.

EDIT: I've got this
[image: I've got this,]

But I want this
[image: But I want this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally chose to abandon the use of a checkbox, as I guess it's hard-coded in that checkboxes are behind buttons.

I've found that the toggleButton does what I need too.
This one is in front of the button.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed your margins and non-needed code. Try the following layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:text="Button 1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
        />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CheckBox"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button1" 
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button 2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Edit**: It looks like drawing over button is not possible. In the edited layout you have a bottom margin of button1 equal to height of the checkbox. You can distribute this height equally to bottom margin of button1 and top-margin of button 2. In support of my claim you can see the following layout, which gives what you want. In this example I have replaced upper button by a textview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button 1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:background="#ddd"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
        />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CheckBox"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button1"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button 2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: That did do things... But not what I wanted to happen.

Comment: @ggblbl What did you want?

Comment: I've added pictures in my question now.